# problems in DDt testing in apache poi

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testing, apache-poi, ddt

In my maven project the excel file is not opening, the eclipse does not support excel file as i have changed many version of apache poi but the issue remained same.When i tried to run my maven project the error occured remained same at every single time as nullpointexception.Please recommend any solution.

I want to take data from external source(i.e. excel) in my maven project , so i add dependency of apache poi version 5.2.2 from maven repository.The txt file are running perfectly but in case of  excel file it does not run at all , or even read it from the test resources in my maven project.i also changed many versions of apache poi in my ide eclipse at my maven project.But the case remains same.So what should i do ,kindly suggest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.